# SQL, Contar registros que tienen valores repetidos en un campo

Tags: mysql, sql

No tengo mucha experiencia con `SQL` y recién estoy empezando, estuve investigando un buen rato pero no logre el resultado que esperaba.

Mi tabla se llama `productos`, donde hay un campo de `producto_id, descripción y marca`.

Por curiosidad quería saber la cantidad de marcas con la que se estaba trabajando en la tabla, por supuesto los productos mas de una vez llevan la misma marca. No pude lograr contar la cantidad de marcas que se encontraban disponibles.

```
SELECT marca, COUNT(marca)
FROM productos
GROUP BY marca
HAVING COUNT(marca) > 1;
```

Intente de esa forma pero solo me devuelve la cantidad de productos que hay por marca y no la cantidad de marcas que existen en la tabla.

Comment: buscaste acerca de distinct?

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener *"cantidad de marcas que existen en la tabla"*, necesitas utilizar la combinación [`COUNT(DISTINCT expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) la cual:

> Devuelve un recuento del número de filas con diferentes valores de `expr` no `NULL`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT marca)
FROM productos;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8psgWLoECuyn47qFA32fX/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres conocer la cantidad de marcas donde está cada producto, debes mostrar el producto y contar las marcas.

```
SELECT producto_id, COUNT(marca)
FROM productos
GROUP BY producto_id
```

Si prefieres que aparezcan solo los que están en más de una marca, le añades el `HAVING`

```
SELECT producto_id, COUNT(marca)
FROM productos
GROUP BY producto_id
HAVING COUNT(marca) > 1;
```

Entendiendo que no puede haber más de una pareja producto_id, marca. Si este no fuera el caso deberás emplear el `count(distinct marca)`

```
SELECT producto_id, COUNT(distinct marca)
FROM productos
GROUP BY producto_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct marca) > 1;
```

Si lo que quieres es conocer la cantidad de productos que tiene una marca, deberás mostrar la marca y hacer la cuenta:

```
SELECT marca, COUNT(producto_id)
FROM productos
GROUP BY marca
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber la cantidad de marcas (el numero total de registros diferentes) dentro de tu tabla productos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT count(marcas) as cantidad_total_marcas
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT marca as marcas
    FROM productos;
)
```

Comment: Esta sentencia te va a dar siempre 1, ya que al hacer un count, solo vas a obtener una fila, luego cuentas esa fila y te va a dar 1.

Answer (score 0):

me pueden ayudar, tengo codigo donde me busca en la tabla los Nombre de Equipo Duplicados pero con serial y usuario diferente; pero me gustaria que alli mismo me busque los que estan cn el mismo nombre repetido y mismo usuario repetido para ese equipo.
_
SELECT e1.Equipo, e1.Serial, e1.User
FROM epo e1
JOIN (
SELECT Equipo
FROM epo
GROUP BY Equipo
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Serial) > 1 AND COUNT(User) > 1
) e2 ON e1.Equipo = e2.Equipo;

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/388154)

Comment: Hola Jose bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.